# Using TCPDF as an engine through CakePDF

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf

I'm using [Ceeram's CakePDF plugin](https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf) on CakePHP 2.2. It makes generating PDFs using Cake's layouts and views very easy and for the most part I have not had any problems with it.

However, I want to be able to access some of the more advanced features of TCPDF, specifically the barcode features.

If I was using TCPDF directly, I could just do `$pdf->writeBarcode();` but as I'm using TCPDF as an engine in the CakePDF Plugin, I'm not sure how to go about accessing it, or if it's even possible.

`$CakePdf->writeBarcode();` doesn't work, but then I wouldn't really have expected it to. There is nothing in Ceeram's docs that mentions it, though.

Comment: Well, as per @Oldsksool's answer, it would be possible if I extended the plugin but I don't have the time (or skill!) to do that. I ended up using another library for this but I can't remember which one. I'm about to board a flight but when I'm at the other end I'll check and see what it was I did :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not support that by default, it just converts your view into a rendered PDF, but it won't let you access the "advanced" functionalities of your PDF Engine. Of course you are always free to extend the plugin to do allow this feature. I reckon you'd have to add it in the `Pdf/CakePdf.php` class file to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks @Oldskool - that is what I suspected but I wasn't sure if I was missing something obvious or not :-)